# Jenkins, xvfb and selenium

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, xvfb

I have been attempting to follow the instructions here to get the Xvfb plugin running:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Currently the xvfb executable is at `/usr/bin/Xvfb`.

My project configuration and Jenkins config are identical to the instructions, however i am getting this error:

> ERROR: No Xvfb installations defined, please define one in the configuration. Once defined you''ll need to choose one under Advanced options for Xvfb plugin job settings and save job configuration.

I have also tried putting the path to the executable in the Jenkins config, with had no change on the outcome.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 11):

You must define a Xfvb installation in "Manage Jenkins" => "Configure System" => "Xvfb installation"

Comment: I've tried this, but my installation configurations won't save.

Comment: just put any name for the config and  /usr/bin for the path

Comment: At the moment, this option is locate under "Global Tool Configuration" (http://jenkisHost:jenkinsPort/configureTools/) but not "Configure System"

Answer (score 8):

You must define installation Xvfb on Jenkins. Access **Manage Jenkins** >> **Global Tool Configuration**. In Section **[Xvfb installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lNU3.png)**, put name and fill the field "**Directory in which to find Xvfb executable**" with **/usr/bin**.

[image]

Comment: I'm using jenkins pipeline and Xvfb is configured as this image. but when I execute the job which have xvfb wrapper i'm getting the error "ERROR: No Xvfb installations defined, please define one in the configuration. Once defined you''ll need to choose one under Advanced options for Xvfb plugin job settings and save job configuration."

Answer (score 2):

> Currently the xvfb executable is at /usr/bin/Xvfb

No, default xvfb location is `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

With the version 1.10 of the plugin I couldn't save the properties. After upgrading to version 1.12, it started saving.